# yii2 change gridview model

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii-form

I am maintaining a form with a model and a grid of child records. I want the grid to show url of the child, not the parent.

I have two database tables which share a parent-child relationship. I showed only the important fields.

```
describe ops;
+---------------+--------------+
| serial_number | int(11)      |
+---------------+--------------+
describe opsitem;
+---------------+--------------+
| opsitem_id    | int(11)      |
| ops_id        | int(11)      |   # foreign key
| serial_number | int(11)      |
+---------------+--------------+
```

In my controller, I display a form for Ops, then create an activeRecord for the child records - Opsitem

```
class OpsController extends Controller

    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ops_id]);
        } else {

            $searchModel = new OpsitemSearch();
            $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(
                ['OpsitemSearch' => ['ops_id' => $model->ops_id]]
            );

            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

My form contains form fields for ops (parent) and then a grid containing oppsitem (child) records

```
// $model is Parent - Ops
<?php echo $this->render('_form', [
    'model' => $model,
 ]) ?>
 // $searchModel is Opsitem - Child
<?php echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => [
                'ops_item_id',
                'ops_id',
                'serial_number'
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                    'template' => '{update}{delete}',
                ],
            ],
        ]); ?>
```

Clicking on the 'update' button on the grid is pointing me to `url`:

> /ops/update?id=1234

I want

> /opsitem/update?id=1234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `controller` property for change controller.
Like as,

```
<?php echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => [
                'ops_item_id',
                'ops_id',
                'serial_number'
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                    'template' => '{update}{delete}',
                    'controller' => 'opsitem', 
                ],
            ],
        ]); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I see it (now) in the docs (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html) but would never have spotted it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize `gridview` Button. For Example,

```
'template' => '{update} {delete}',
'buttons' => [
            'update' => function ($url, $model) {
                  return Html::a('Update',\Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['/opsitem/update', 'id' => 1234]),['class' => 'any class']);
                    },
            ],
```

Comment: Thanks, @GAMITG's solution is more, eh, elegant, but this is a very practical approach too.